# Resize an image in an image viewer app I am working on

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

this is my first post here, I just started learning the language. I am currently trying to create a very simple app that allows you to open an image file, it displays in the root window, and the window resizes itself based on the image size. The image also changes scale when you drag the window smaller or larger.

So far I have created a menu bar with two dropdowns menus, my file browser works fine, and I can get an image to display on the canvas, however, the window doesn't resize to fit the image, and the image size is static. I have looked at a lot of youtube videos and tutorial sites, but most of them just tell you how to resize an image to a specific size, which isn't what I'm looking for. I'm currently using the PIL library to attempt this. Is there a specific module I should be using that I haven't found yet? I thought to resize would do the trick but that doesn't work. Or is this more in-depth than I thought?

Here's the link to my GitHub, still figuring that out too: https://github.com/jackcryan/spicy-eggplant/blob/master/Imageviewer.py

Right now I can open an image directly and have it be resizable in the window, but it doesn't work with the file browser. However, if I take out the bit of code relating to image resizing then I can select and load files on a canvas but the image size is static.  Thank you for reading, I appreciate any criticism or help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make yours variables copy_of_image and label Global in each def where they are used.
After it work fine.